# Elasticsearch gives a high response time under very low throughput and vice versa

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene, elasticsearch-rest-client

I have configured a self-managed Elasticsearch cluster with three nodes on Google Cloud VMs. The cluster consists of four primary shards and four replica shards.

However, when I deployed Elasticsearch on the production environment, I noticed the following observations:

1. When throughput is high (100 RPM), the p99 is under 30 ms.
2. When throughput is low (2-3 RPM) , the p99 is around 1500 ms.

A noticeable trend is that the response time is initially high for the first few requests, but as the number of requests increases, the response time improves.

Below is my elasticsearch client implementation,

```
public ElasticSearchClusterConnectionFactory(List<String> hosts, int port) {
        HttpHost[] httpHosts = hosts.stream()
                .map(host -> new HttpHost(host, port))
                .toArray(HttpHost[]::new);

        RestClientBuilder.HttpClientConfigCallback httpClientConfigCallback = httpClientBuilder ->
                httpClientBuilder
                        .setDefaultHeaders(List.of(
                                new org.apache.http.message.BasicHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString()),
                                new BasicHeader(HttpHeaders.CONNECTION, "keep-alive")
                        ))
                        .addInterceptorLast((HttpResponseInterceptor) (response, context) -> response.addHeader("X-Elastic-Product", "Elasticsearch"))
                        .setMaxConnTotal(400)
                        .setMaxConnPerRoute(200)
                        .setConnectionReuseStrategy((response, context) -> true)
                        .setKeepAliveStrategy((response, context) -> Duration.ofMinutes(10).toMillis());

        RestClient restClient = RestClient.builder(httpHosts)
                .setHttpClientConfigCallback(httpClientConfigCallback)
                .setRequestConfigCallback(requestConfigBuilder -> requestConfigBuilder
                    .setConnectionRequestTimeout(0)
                    .setConnectTimeout(1000)
                    .setSocketTimeout(200))
            .build();

        ElasticsearchTransport transport = new RestClientTransport(
                restClient, new JacksonJsonpMapper());

        // Creating the API client
        this.client = new ElasticsearchClient(transport);
    }
```

My finding is at very throughput (2-3 RPM), its not reusing the connection and creating a new one but when the throughput(100 RPM) is high, it uses the connection from the pool and requests are served within a very small milliseconds. I have attempted to address the issue by setting the ConnectionReuseStrategy and KeepAliveStrategy to optimize connection reuse. However, these changes did not yield significant improvements in performance, particularly at low throughput.

To enhance performance under low throughput conditions, I would appreciate guidance on additional steps or optimizations that can be undertaken.

Comment: could you add some logs including the response time and the elastic took time. it can help to find out whether the problem is from the cluster itself, or the client properties we used.